# Using map::at() in pre c++0x

Tags: c++, stl

I was happy see that map::at() was added to c++11, but upon digging around, I see that's it's already defined in gcc libraries, and works with -std=c++0x, *and* c++98.

Is using this method for code compiled with a standard before c++0x considered portable?

Comment: It's part of the standard from c++11, so yes, any implementation which supports C++11 should support it.

Comment: @JesseGood: The OP mentions `-std=c++0x` though. Is that equivalent to `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent, although `-std=c++0x` is deprecated for `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @AndrewP: The question title says "pre C++0x", but you are specifying `-std=c++0x`. Which one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misinterpreting what `-std=c++0x` means. From [C dialect options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html):

> 'c++11'
>
> 'c++0x'
>
> The 2011 ISO C++ standard plus amendments. Support for C++11 is still experimental, and may change in incompatible ways in future
>   releases. The name 'c++0x' is deprecated.

As you can see `c++0x` and `c++11` are equivalent and `c++0x` is deprecated.

Comment: And it certainly doesn't mean "pre-c++0x"

Comment: @AndrewP: It has existed in libstc++ for a while, but there is no guarantee that exists in other C++98 libraries (for example, microsoft implemented it from MSVC2010).